# C# Console Application using assignment operators

Tags: c#, console-application, assignment-operator

What i am trying to do is, I have `int x = 100;` so whenever I write anything in Console for example I wrote 'wrong' 10 should be subtracted from '100'.

I am trying to do with using assignment operator `x -=10` can someone give me any idea how it will work?

Comment: `x -= 5` is subtracting 5 from `x`. Does it produce an unexpected result?

Comment: have you tried what you mentioned ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I tried using " if " condition. I am new to Console can't figure it out anything

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry I edited to  `x -= 10 `

Comment: @abdulwadood can you show the code you are trying with a minmal example ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad my code didnt make any sense it would become much more harder to understand than what I asked lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I have a feeling that you are completely new to c# I will provide you an example about what you are trying to do. But next time when you want to ask a question consider that you must provide an example code of what have you tried so far:

```
int x = 100;

while (true)
{
    if (Console.ReadLine() == "wrong")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("x = " + (x -= 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works.Yeah I will next time .

Comment: Can I know what `while (true)` did here?

Comment: @abdulwadood `while (true)` is infinite loop. Since condition inside parentheses are always equal to true.